# How to split data and save min value of startTime to variable

Tags: python-3.x

i wan't to create the script which can save from csv startTime and endTime to variable, for example i have different startTime values(11:59:12, 11:59:19, 11:59:22) and different endTime values (12:59:12, 12:59:19, 12:59:22), i want to store for startTime to varible only lowest one, which has been started early than others and endTime which has been ended last.
So from this examples must be stored to variable startTime = 11:59:12 and endTime = 11:59:22.
Could you tell me please what i gonna do. my script looks right now like that:

```
import csv
import datetime
import time


data = list(csv.reader(open('C:\\Documents and Settings\\Lemur\\Desktop\\TestResults.csv', 'r')))

startTimeWithoutCp = ""

for x in xrange(4, 13):
   cpStartTime = (data[x][6])+ ":" + " " + (data[x][12][10:19])
   cpEndTime =   (data[x][6])+ ":" + " " + (data[x][13][10:19])
   startTimeWithoutCp += (data[x][12][11:19])
#print("CP Start Times is: ", cpStartTime)
#print("CP End Time is: ", cpEndTime)
print(startTimeWithoutCp)

# The output results looks like that:
# 11:59:0811:59:1211:59:1911:59:2211:59:2811:59:3211:59:3711:59:4211:59:47
```

Could you tell me please, how i can split correctly this results and get minimal value from this list. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think you should store your time points in a `list`. Concatenating them into one string (like you do it for `startTimeWithoutCp`) makes it hard to get back the original times. On individual time points, you can use the fact that strings / characters can be sorted:

```
>>> a = '11:20:02'
>>> b = '04:34:12'
>>> c = '04:34:14'
>>> sorted([a, b, c])
['04:34:12', '04:34:14', '11:20:02']
>>> min([a, b, c])
'04:34:12'
```

So given you have your time points in a list, you can just use `min()` and `max()`.
You can split the long string into its pieces by using Python's slicing notation:

```
d = '11:59:0811:59:1211:59:1911:59:2211:59:2811:59:3211:59:3711:59:4211:59:47'
print([d[i:i + 8] for i in range(0, len(d), 8)])
```

Comment: I understand this, but can you tell me please how i can converte: ["11:59:0811:59:1211:59:1911:59:2211:59:2811:59:3211:59:3711:59:4211:59:47"] to ["11:59:08", "11:59:12", "11:59:19", "11:59:22", "11:59:28", "11:59:32", "11:59:37", "11:59:42", "11:59:47"] ?